# Go to the second fragment (activity) not working in kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-intent, methods

I want to switch from `modifyfragment` to the `loginfragment` by cliquing on the button `go_login_page_id` so i tried to insert the code below:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        go_login_page_id.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, ModifyFragment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Try to show login activity")
        }
        login_id_re.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }
        go_login_page_id.setOnClickListener {
            var fr = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            fr?.replace(R.id.ModifyFragment, LoginFragment())
            fr?.commit()
        }
    }
```

the fragment **register_activity.xml**'s code which shows the fragment contain the main container and the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/register_view_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.menu.a9dli3.ui.modifyFragment.ModifyFragment"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/surname_id_re"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name_id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_id" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_id_re"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/surname_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/surname_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surname_id_re" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_id_re"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/phone_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/phone_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_id_re" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_id_re"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="@string/menu_send"
        android:text="Loging"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_id_re" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/go_login_page_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="I Have an account"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_id_re" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email_id_re"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_id_re" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_id_re"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="150dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email "
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see in the **modifyFragment.kt**'s code:

```
package com.menu.a9dli3.ui.modifyFragment

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.menu.a9dli3.ui.login.LoginFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_modify_profile.*
import android.R

class ModifyFragment: Fragment() {


    private lateinit var modifyviewmodel: ModifyViewModel

    override fun onCreateView (inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        modifyviewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ModifyViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(com.menu.a9dli3.R.layout.fragment_modify_profile, container, false)
        val templatemode: TextView = root.findViewById(com.menu.a9dli3.R.id.text_slidemodify)
         modifyviewmodel.text.observe( this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { templatemode.text= it } )
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        login_id_re.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }

        go_login_page_id.setOnClickListener {
            var fr = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            fr?.replace(R.id.ModifyFragment, LoginFragment())
            fr?.commit()
        }
    }

    private fun performRegister() {
        val email = email_id_re.text.toString()
        val password = password_id_re.text.toString()
        val name = surname_id_re.text.toString()
        val surname = surname_id_re.toString()
        val phone = phone_id_re.toString()

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty() || surname.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter all the text fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
            return
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Email is: $email")
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Password: $password")
    }
}
```

there was an error **unresolved reference ModifyFragment**,
I tried to insert **modify_list** and **login_list** fragments in the **main_activity.xml** in the purpose that the android studio suggests to me these fragments, but steel the same things.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/modify_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.menu.a9dli3.ui.modifyFragment.ModifyFragment"
        />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/login_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.menu.a9dli3.ui.login.LoginFragment"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

can you explain to me the best practices concerning intents and life cycle for creating methods (onCreate, on viewCreated and onCreateview) in the two cases Activity and fragment.

Comment: you shouldn't need to have 2 fragment in `main_activity.xml`

Comment: `.observe( this,` should be `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this`

Answer (score 1):

You have use `onClickListener` for one button twice and in first `listener` you are try below code

```
trying to call fragment with intent
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        login_id_re.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }

        go_login_page_id.setOnClickListener {
            var fr = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            fr?.replace(R.id.ModifyFragment, LoginFragment())
            fr?.commit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not the main issue.

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: No i did not bro

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment)) function documentation the first parameter of replace function should be a reference to **view container** such as a `FrameLayout`. Edit your `layout.xml` to have a FrameLayout which is supposed to contain the current fragment of your activity, as explained in the [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui).
Right now you're passing `R.id.ModifyFragment` (which is not a valid view container) to replace function, so your app is raising the error "there was an error unresolved reference `ModifyFragment`"

Comment: `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/register_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">` this is my FrameLayout with the id register_view_id but it steel not working in my code.